# How can I paste data from one spreadsheet to the last column of another?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Im trying to copy data from a whole bunch of different workbooks into one master sheet, pasting just the values in the next blank column. It all seems to be functional but always fails when it attempts to paste into the master sheet. I've tried looking at similar problems elsewhere but i cant seem to get them to work with what I am trying to do.

I have grabbed the bulk of this code off somewhere else and modified to suit, as you may be able to tell from some of the left over comments

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim colDest As Long
Dim Dest As Worksheet

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue this is where the work occurs
      Set Dest = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
      colDest = Dest.Cells(1, Dest.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("b3:u83").Copy
      Dest.Range(1, colDest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

EDIT: Error occurs on this line:

```
Dest.Range(1, colDest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

EDIT2: Changing the attempt to Paste with an attempt to write a value to the cell ie:

```
Dest.Cells(1, colDest) = "Test"
```

Correctly types "Test" into the next available column on the master sheet for every workbook that was opened from the directory.
Apparently changing 'Range' to 'Cells' works, which i thought i tried yesterday but was throwing a different error complaining i wasn't selecting the correct size cell

Comment: This line `colDest = Dest.Cells(1, Dest.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column` should be: `colDest = Dest.Cells(1, Dest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1` . When you use `Dest.Columns.Count`it gives you back the max number of columns for that sheet, so going to the right is not an option, going to the left will give you the last written column for row 1 and the adding +1 will give you the first blank column for row 1.

Comment: i posted this in quite a rush and wasnt able to pull up the error itself at the time but, it crashes when attempting to paste, not when attempting to find the last column. I'll update main question with Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this basically what you need to do is add 1 to the `colDest` to give you the next empty column.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim colDest As Long
Dim Dest As Worksheet

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue this is where the work occurs
      Set Dest = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
      colDest = Dest.Cells(1, Dest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("b3:u83").Copy
      Dest.Range(1, colDest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, did you read my comment? This will throw an error. You can't go right after the last column on the sheet. is `xlToLeft`.

Comment: @Damian I did modify it to xlLeft but looking at it now it didn’t do it for some reason.

Comment: Yes, because OP's code was the same, you added the +1 which is right, but also needed to go left, not right.

Comment: @Damian yes I know I must have done something wrong and then undo the changes and forgot to do the xlToLeft.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some guidelines on how to find last column an import value after last column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            'Last Column using UsedRange (NOT A GOOD IDEA)
            LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
            'Last Column using specific row 7
            LastColumn = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            'Add a value in row 5 & after last column
            .Cells(5, LastColumn + 1).Value = ""

        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Set Dest = Workbooks("Master.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
  colDest = Dest.Cells(1, Dest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
  wb.Worksheets(1).Range("b3:u83").Copy
  Dest.Cells(1, colDest).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Correctly inputs the Data where I need it, the 'ToLeft' made a difference but 'Range' wouldn't allow me to paste where 'Cells' does